# How to declare multiple ports in swagger yml file

Tags: npm, swagger

I have a swagger app in `generator-express-no-stress`. I want to document two different apis which is already running on different ports suppose on is running on `8080` and other is running on `9090`. Below is my swagger yml file in which I document apis running on `8080` but in the same I want to document `9090` too. Please help me to solve this below is my file:-

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: DIVI
  description: My cool app
host: ip:8080
basePath: /api/v1
tags:
  - name: Explorer
    description: Apis for explorer
  # - name: Specification
  #   description: The swagger API specification
schemes:
  - https
  - http
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json


definitions:
  ExampleBody:
    type: object
    title: example
    required:
      - name
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
        example: no_stress

paths:
  /get-data:
    get:
      tags:
        - Explorer
      description: Fetch latest data
      responses:
        200:
          description: Returns all examples
  /get-version-data/{version}:
    get:
      tags:
        - Explorer
      parameters:
        - name: version
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The version of the explorer to retrieve
          type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return the example with the specified id
        404:
          description: Example not found
  /get-data/{search}:
    get:
      tags:
        - Explorer
      parameters:
        - name: search
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The search of the explorer to retrieve
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return the example with the specified id
        404:
          description: Example not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure 2 more .yml file. (ex: **applidaction-dev.yml** and **application-test.yml**).

in config file:
in applidaction-dev.yml -> set host: ip:8080
in application-test.yml -> host: ip:9090

and before run your app set Active profile: **dev** (for 8080) or set **test** (for 9090)